# Android Studio starting in debug mode by default

Tags: debugging, android-studio

I have been working on a project, and when I run the project in android studio it had been running correct and when I ran in debug mode it ran correctly.

All of a sudden, when I try to run the project normally, it pops up on the device waiting for debugger

and in the logcat I get this:

```
02-07 10:38:46.444    3968-3968/com.geog.test D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-07 10:38:46.784    3968-3968/com.geog.test W/ActivityThread﹕ Application com.geog.visitdub is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
02-07 10:38:46.804    3968-3968/com.geog.test I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk
```

and it goes no further.  I don't know why this is happening, there is no debug command in the manifest, I have killed the adb and restarted as I did with android studio.

It's a real pain in the a*** as I can't run the app without going through debug mode.  If anyone has any ideas I'd like to hear them

Thanks

Comment: restart your Android Device once and let me know also check there should not be any breakpoints in java classes.

Comment: a simple device restart...thank you!!  sometimes it's the most simple things that can be overlooked!  Can you put that in an answer so I can accept

Comment: Sometime it happens :)

Comment: I rebooted my device and it works.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Restart your Android Device once and also check there should not be any breakpoints in your java classes.

Comment: Restart helped. By the way, you can view breakpoints by pressing CMD+SHIFT+F8 in Android Studio.

Answer (score 5):

The above suggestions were too invasive for me so I digged a little more into it. The following solution works for me in android studio:

- Start debugging. (You'll get the wait chunk message here)
- Select the Debug pane with the bug icon.
- press the small cross at the side menu.
- press "Force close" on your device.
- Restart debugging.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, there was an `AsyncTask` whose `doInBackground()` method called `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger()`, and this was being picked up even in run mode. Disabling the line fixed it. Restarting the device didn't help.

Comment: Don't know _why_, as the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#waitForDebugger%28%29) don't indicate it should block a normal run, so would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

try this , always work :

1 - close Android Studio and any other IDE you have opened (maybe you have Eclipse also running?) and emulator instances;

2 - remove USB cable from PC and restart your phone if you use one ;

3 - run adb kill-server from console;

4 - open Android Studio;

5 - click on run/debug;

6 - when the window to select the device appears, attach your device to USB and USB to your computer;

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was a service to which I had added android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger(). The service was in a separate process by defining in the manifest android:process=":sepprocess"; after removing this line (such that the service is in the same process as the main activity), debugging started to work in the service and I did not experience the

```
    I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk
```

anymore.

Answer (score 2):

First clear all the break points from your project using ctrl+shift+F8 for windows or for mac cmd+shift+F8. Restart your android device. Then run

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there are multiple debuggers. I have native code running in my app.

I cleared it by selecting the Debugger and Process from Run->Attach Debugger to Process

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the emulator and recreated. It worked for me.